# Better way to combine two objects with linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Some of our data isn't the cleanest. For instance, if a person gave their address two different ways, he may appear in output twice: once with "RD" and again with "Road."

Funnily, enough, half their data appears in one record and half in the other. So...

```
Johnny, Larsen Rd, Tuesday, 4 milk bottles
Johnny, Larsen Road, Tuesday, 3 milk bottles
```

Johnny's consumption for Tuesday was, in fact, 7 bottles of milk. I'm trying to write a LINQ that merges these two objects without too much pain, but this is all I have so far:

```
var records = report.GroupBy(r => r.Date)
    .Select(n => new MilkBottleRecord() {
        Name = report.First().Name,
        Address = report.First().Address,
        Date = report.First().Date,
        Bottles = n.Sum(x => x.Bottles),
    });
```

Any suggestions?

I should point out that A) this is not our data, so we can't really do the cleanup, and B) we're getting it via CSV rather than from an SQL query.

Also, the only relevant information in the query above is the date because I already separated out the different accounts in a prior query. Since that one is fine, I didn't figure it was worth your time to include it here.

Comment: If the object were this small, this method would be fine, but the real thing is substantially larger and more complex than the MilkBottleRecord above.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is... is the only interchangeable words `Rd` and `Road`, or is there a list of word pairs that need to work like that? It seems in your query like the date is the only important selector, which means Alice and John that get delivery on the same day will be lumped together...?

Comment: Then you maybe think about how to tune the DB by adding some indexes.

Comment: what if there are two different Johnnys? If name + address is no longer enough to know what is unique, what is the real key for these records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
IEqualityComparer<MilkBottleRecord> comparer = /* instantiate a comparer */
var records = report.GroupBy(x => x, comparer)
                    .Select(g => new MilkBottleRecord(g.Key) {
                        Bottles = g.Sum(x => x.Bottles))
                    });
```

The basic idea is: externalize your comparison logic, create a copy constructor that allows you to duplicate the salient information, then overwrite the Bottles field with the Sum.

Comment: I think the constructor suggestions I have received may be about the best I can do for voiding the ridiculous select statement in the original.

Comment: @archer884: Frankly, I up-voted zmbq's solution. This is a data sanitization issue that you probably want to take care of in the CSV, not in C#. If you're viewing this initial import as the sanitization step, however, then I would go with one of the copy-constructor/equality comparers.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using painful-to-write queries, wouldn't it be better to go over the database and merge the duplicate records? If you do that, your queries will look a lot nicer.

Comment: Sorry; this is getting loaded from a CSV. :)

Comment: Garbage in, garbage out, Fix the garbage then everything else should fall into place. +1

Comment: You can still go over the CSV and merge the duplicate records before trying to extract data from it. The C# merging code will be a lot clearer than the complex query code.

Comment: I wouldn't use LINQ for merging those records. It turns out horrible, and impossible to maintain.

Comment: How would you merge records straight from the text file?

Comment: You can turn the file into a list of objects first if you want to.  I'd build a `Dictionary<KeyType, <List<MyObject>>` with lists of to-be-merged objects. Then I'd go over each list and merge it. And only then I would go about generating reports.

Comment: That's actually *exactly* what I'm doing; it's just that I'm using LINQ to do the merging rather than ... Well, see, that's the thing. I haven't thought of another way to do it that wouldn't be even more tangled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34490/discussion-between-archer884-and-zmbq)

Answer (score 0):

Fulfillment companies use [CASS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_Accuracy_Support_System) software to fix and normalize addresses. If you are doing something professionally, you might look into that.

Otherwise, you could do something like:

```
string NormalizeAddress(string str)
{
    // should probably be a bit more intelligent than this, but maybe not.
    str = str.ToUpperInvariant();
    str = str.Replace ("ROAD", "RD");
    return str;
}

var records = report.GroupBy(r =>
                         Tuple.Create(r.Date, NormalizeAddress(r.Address)))
```

Comment: We'd love to fix it, but it's not our data.

Comment: To be fair, your suggestion would actually work fine for this case. Other cases down the line might not be as easily dealt with; that's why I thought it would be best to go based on the (basically constant, for a given date) datetime.Date field.

Comment: CASS is very safe (certified by USPS, and required by them for some discounts), I recommend it. We use it for most of our clients where I work. Either way, you want to either fix the addresses, an aggregate group by (simpler to write) against a normalized address as shown here, or a custom comparator (maybe better perf) which does normalizing internally.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the data structure, how about something like

```
var records = report.GroupBy(r => r.Date)
    .Select(n => new MilkBottleRecord(report.First, n.Sum(x => x.Bottles)));
```

and a constructor

```
MilkBottleReport(MilkBottleReport original, int newBottles);
```

Answer (score 0):

As an answer to your question - create a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor) and your LINQ looks nicer.
But as archer884 said, LINQ might choke; and I add that doing a big chunk of data with no way of knowing of progress is bad - iterate record by record.
Also: as zmbq noted - move the cleaning of data to it's own module/dll/assembly/machine/process/business.

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is to sanitize and normalize your data. Decide whether spelled-out or abbreviated types of thoroughfares (Road/Rd, Avenue/Av/Ave, Street/St, Drive/Dr, Lane/Ln) are to be used in addresses, then change your data to conform to the standards you've chosen and de-dupe.

Another part of the answer is to use an immutable identifier to differentiate records. You may well end up with two distinct people named "Johnny" that live on a "Larsen Road". It could even be the same Larsen Road; John, and the nickname Johnny, are common enough that there could easily be two Johns who go by Johnny living on a specific Larsen Road; they would hopefully be differentiated by last name, and by lot or apartment number, but if you think any of this data is suspect then you still have problems. The solution is a unique identifier, such as an account number, allowing you to positively differentiate two different people named Johnny living on Larsen Road, or conversely to identify discrepancies in any other "uniquely identifying information" that would otherwise cause you to mistake one person for two.

LINQ isn't a cure-all, and while you may well come up with a general-purpose normalizing query using LINQ, I wouldn't want to come in behind you and maintain it. There are other tools available for sanitizing real-world data into something a computer can match on.

Comment: Again, there is an identifier; I didn't include it in the sample because the sample includes records for only one positively-identified person.